# Error while attempting to inflate LayoutInflater

Tags: android

I am trying to inflate the layout "panel_stream" into my current view, but it crashes with the error message:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML
>   file line #2: Error inflating class

```
 public void loadContent() {

    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.mainRLayout);

    //this is the line where it crashes
    View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.panel_stream, parent);

 TextView title =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.panelTitle);
    title.setText("your text");
    TextView author = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.panelAuthor);
    author.setText("your text");
    TextView content = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.panelContent);
    content.setText("your text");
    ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.contentHost);
    Log.d("LOGGINGSTUFF","5");
    insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

}
```

activity_board_stream_view.xml (The View I am trying to post into):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.company.panels.BoardView"
android:background="@color/background"
android:id="@+id/mainRLayout">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/contentScroller" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/contentHost">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

panel_stream.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
android:clickable="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/panel_header_shape"
    android:contextClickable="true"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Title Here"
        android:id="@+id/panelTitle"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Author"
        android:id="@+id/panelAuthor"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/panelTitle"
        android:textColor="#eeeeee"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/panel_shape">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/panel_shape"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/panelContent" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Crashlog:

```
04-26 21:57:15.486 16137-16137/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.company.panels, PID: 16137
                                               android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                   at com.company.panels.BoardView.loadContent(BoardView.java:96)
                                                   at com.company.panels.BoardView.onCreateOptionsMenu(BoardView.java:42)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2852)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:341)
                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:258)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1312)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1592)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:91)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:130)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                   at com.company.panels.BoardView.loadContent(BoardView.java:96) 
                                                   at com.company.panels.BoardView.onCreateOptionsMenu(BoardView.java:42) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2852) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:341) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:258) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1312) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1592) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:91) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:130) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                   at com.company.panels.BoardView.loadContent(BoardView.java:96) 
                                                   at com.company.panels.BoardView.onCreateOptionsMenu(BoardView.java:42) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2852) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:341) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:258) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1312) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1592) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:91) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:130) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=522; index=1332
                                                   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getValueAt(TypedArray.java:1132)
                                                   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:661)
                                                   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4207)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                   at com.company.panels.BoardView.loadContent(BoardView.java:96) 
                                                   at com.company.panels.BoardView.onCreateOptionsMenu(BoardView.java:42) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2852) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:341) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:258) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1312) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1592) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:91) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:130) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: @Skyler : every id you have given should be in `lowercase` and what is `panel_header_shape` ?

Comment: Are you using this View in an adapter?If yes Please post the adapter class too@Skyler

Comment: @AndiGeeky Its just a shape drawable

Comment: @Skyler : try to add below solutions and check again if it works or not..!!

Comment: add BoardView.java

Comment: I'm not sure how the below answers address the problem... `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=522; index=1332`

Comment: @cricket_007 That's because you don't know how this problem was formely exposed here.

Comment: have you did code in activity or Fragment

Comment: @VishalHalani I'm using activities

Comment: @GeraldoFreitas I can see the edit history.

Comment: @Skyler just use Getsystemservice not with application context

Comment: @Skyler so you want to add dynamic content right?? in scroll view or  out side scroll view

Comment: try vi.inflate(R.layout.panel_stream, parent, false);

Comment: @VisualHalani inside the scroll view.

Comment: ok dear then why you take id of realative layout. as parent .you have to add in linear layout.

Comment: @VishalHalani Either way, the error is still produced

Comment: @USKMobility, this still produces the same error

Comment: why you not use listview?? i think you are try to do same thing

Comment: i have posted code implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to code like this.

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.contentHost);

    //this is the line where it crashes
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, parent);

    TextView title =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.panelTitle);
    title.setText("Title");
    TextView author = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.panelAuthor);
    author.setText("author");
    TextView content = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.panelContent);
    content.setText("content");
```

And your activity_mainstream layout should like this.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.company.panels.BoardView"
android:id="@+id/contentScroller">
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/contentHost">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout></ScrollView>
```

Comment: It longer crashes, but it just entered the main activity without showing the layout

Comment: have you replaced activity_layoutmain2 with your panelstream

Comment: Sorry for late response, but this got it to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the name space in your layout xml file and that causes the error.

Include name space in your layout file's root tag as,

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...>
```

**Edit :**

Remove `orientation` attribute from `RelativeLayout` tag since it can only be used with `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I just noticed this was already in the file, I had just formatted the post wrong and it wasn't showing up

Comment: Please read the logcat. There is an index out of bounds exception

Answer (score -1):

At least the first line needs to contain:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
"your other attributes here">
```

Comment: This was already in the file, I had just formatted the post wrong and it wasn't showing up

Comment: Please put the panel_stream.xml again, because now it is incomplete as for example the first relative layout hasn't a closing tag.